# Hints for this. Let $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin nx}{n^2}$. Find the values for $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(x)dx$ and $f'(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $\,f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin nx}{n^2}$. Find the values for $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(x)\,dx$ and $f'(x)$.

The unique idea i have is as the integral is a linear operator may be i could integrate each one of the term in the series, but I'm not pretty sure.

Comment: Do you mean to start at $n=1$? I'm pretty sure $f(x)$ is ill-defined if it starts at $n=0$.

Comment: Yes, sorry! You are right $n=1$

Comment: You absolutely can integrate (and differentiate)  the terms.

Answer (score 4):

We have $\left|\frac{\sin(nx)}{n^2}\right|\leq\frac{1}{n^2}$ and $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}$ is finite, hence we have uniform convergence, $f(x)$ is a continuous function and we are allowed to apply termwise integration, leading to
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}f(x)\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi n}{4}\right)}{n^3}=\frac{35}{32}\zeta(3). $$
Differentiation is subtler. The formal derivative
$$ g(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos(nx)}{n} $$
is pointwise convergent, by [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test), only if $x\not\in 2\pi\mathbb{Z}$. It is the $2\pi$-periodic extension of the function that over $(0,2\pi)$ equals $-\log\left|2\sin(x/2)\right|$. Now you may prove that $f(x)$ is not differentiable at any point of $2\pi\mathbb{Z}$ and apply [the dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) to
$$ \lim_{N\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{x}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\cos(nt)}{n}\,dt $$
to prove that $g(x)$ equals $f'(x)$ at any $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus 2\pi\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Great answer! Why does that sum equal $\frac{35}{32}\zeta(3)$? I get how it would be related to $\zeta(3)$ but why that exactly?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut: the sum of interest is $$\sum_{m\geq 0}\left(\frac{1}{(4m+1)^3}+\frac{2}{(4m+2)^3}+\frac{1}{(4m+3)^3}\right) $$ that can be computed from $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^3}=\zeta(3)$ and $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^3}=\eta(3)=\frac{3}{4}\zeta(3).$$

Comment: It is straightforward to check that the sum of interest is just $\zeta(3)+\frac{1}{8}\eta(3)$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Except if I'm missing something, it remains to prove that $f$ is differentiable for $x \neq 2 \pi \mathbb Z$. For that we can use the Abel's uniform convergence test to prove that $g$ converge uniformly on all compact included in $\mathbb R \setminus 2 \pi \mathbb Z$ and the "classical" theorem for derivative of sequences of functions (Theorem 6.3 of http://www.math.ucla.edu/~heilman/teach/af6.pdf for example).

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: I completely agree with you. There still are some details to fill, but since the OP asked for hints, I guessed that to give him just the core of the proof was enough.